History API doesn't work properly on Telegram Desktop
I'm trying to develop a Telegram mini web app using pure js and html on my frontend. To avoid the page reloading I tried to use History API namely pushState(). And I encoutered a strange behaviour, that the pushState() function sends somehow a GET request to my backend server. So I get two GET requests every time I call this function.
const Router = {
  async handleChange(e) {
    const url = e.target.getAttribute('data-url');

    if (url) {
      await axios.get(url).then(res => {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = res.data;
        window.history.pushState(res.data, '', url);
      });
    }
  },
};

Then I discovered that this behaviour is relevant only for the Desktop Telegram App. So by using the phone app or the web version this function sends only one GET request. I'm confused. Is there a solution for that or it's just how the Desktop App works?

Did you find anything?
